# CRUD operations on a SQL CE database

Tags: .net, wpf, sql-server-ce

I have a SQL CE databse in a .net 4.0 WPF application, and nothing i do will write to the database. I can enter data directly, and view what i have entered in the application.

I have tried using a DAL, directly with a SqlCeConnection, using a dataTable, and the suggestions of a hundred tutorials... and nothing throws any errors, yet it does nothing.

Everything i can observe in debug mode looks fine...

This is my first WPF application, but i have written several data-heavy asp.net Web Applications and have never had any problems like this.

Any suggestions are appreciated!

-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will find you have two copies of the database - one in a folder in your project, and one in your `/bin` folder, which is copied there as part of the build process, and it will be the instance in your `/bin` folder that has the entries made via your application.

Comment: :) thank you. you are exactly right. I discovered this about 11:00 last night. I have always used a full blown SQL server in my web deployments, so i am always looking at live data.